# Display a form and the output on the same page

Tags: django

This code will display the form. I can input data, submit the data and the data then displays along with the previous input data from the mySQL DB table where the dat is written, but when the data displays the input form goes away (all expect the submit button that is). I've come across this subject here, but could never quite find the answer that worked for me.

```
**`models.py`**

class UnitPool(models.Model):

    # rack = models.ForeignKey(Rack)
    # platform = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LAB, default='Choose', blank=False)
    rack = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=RACKS, default='Choose', blank=False)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices = PLATFORM, default='Choose',blank=False)
    unit_HW_Serial = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    unit_SW_Serial = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    unit_SKU = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True, default='')


    def __unicode__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return '%s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.rack,
                                         self.platform,
                                         self.unit_HW_Serial,
                                         self.unit_SW_Serial,
                                         self.unit_SKU,
                                         self.comments)

class UUTForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UnitPool
        widgets = {
            'comments': TextInput(attrs={'size': 10}),
        }
        fields = ['location','rack', 'platform','unit_HW_Serial','unit_SW_Serial','unit_SKU','comments']

**forms.html**

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-2'>


{% if title %}
<h1 class='{% if title_align_center %}text-align-center{% endif %}'>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endif %}


<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}

{{ form|crispy }}

<input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='Add Unit' />
</form>

</div>
</div>
</div>

{% if queryset %}
{% if rack != '' %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-3'>
        <h1>Unit Data Entered</h1>
        <table class='table'>
            <td><b>Item</b></td>
            <td><b>Location</b></td>
            <td><b>Rack#</b></td>
            <td><b>Platform</b></td>
            <td><b>HW SN</b></td>
            <td><b>SW SN</b></td>
            <td><b>SKU</b></td>
            <td><b>Comment</b></td>

            {% for instance in queryset %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                    <td>{{ instance.location }}</td>
                    <td>{{ instance.rack }}</td>
                    <td>{{ instance.platform }}</td>
                    <td>{{ instance.unit_HW_Serial }}</td>
                    <td>{{ instance.unit_SW_Serial }}</td>
                    <td>{{ instance.unit_SKU }}</td>
                    <td>{{ instance.comments }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

**views.py**

from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import UnitPool, UUTForm

def labunits(request):
    title = 'Enter Info'
    form = UUTForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
      "title": title,
      "form": form
    }

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()


        queryset = UnitPool.objects.all().order_by('rack','platform') 
        context = {
            "queryset": queryset
        }

    return render(request, "labunits/forms.html", context)
```

Comment: Surely you just need to include the form in the context dictionary inside the `is_valid` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **pass the `form` in the context after calling `.is_valid()`** as [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) also mentioned.

Since you are not passing the `form` in the context again after calling the `.is_valid()` function, the form does not get displayed again in the template.

So, when you are resetting the context, you need to pass the `form` also.

```
def labunits(request):
    title = 'Enter Info'
    form = UUTForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
      "title": title,
      "form": form
    }

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()


        queryset = UnitPool.objects.all().order_by('rack','platform') 
        context = {
            "queryset": queryset,
            "form" : form # pass the form in the context
        }

    return render(request, "labunits/forms.html", context)
```

Comment: Another question. Your suggestion, of course, worked so thanks again. The only thing left is for the data to display to the right of the form as opposed to below it. I'm using 2 colums for the form and 9 colums for the data and wanted the table to list to the right of the form.  I could make my form inline I suppose, but it is 8 entries and that could be a bit cumbersome.

Comment: I am afraid i don't have a better solution for that 2nd problem. Maybe you can ask another question on SO to get solution for that.

Comment: Sounds good. Again, appreciate the soltuion and amazingly quick responses. I'm have to confess I spun-my-wheels a long time with this problem. You saved my " "...

Comment: Glad to help! Also, don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your issue. :)

Comment: Forgive.. how do I accept the answer? I assume you are referring to a button clock or...?